# Enable all possible constraints in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Recently I had to migrate data. For that purpose, I disabled all constraint with this command

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"
```

I have migrated all the data from the old database to the new database. Now I am facing some data conflict that does not allow me to re-enable all my constraint. I tried this command but it didn't work for me

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all"
```

Is there a way to enable all foreign key relations where there is no data conflict?
Please give me the query for do this task.

**NOTE:**
I have about 20 tables that have conflicting data between them. I don't want to enable constraints on them.
I just want to enable constraints on other tables that have no problems (about 200 tables).

Comment: You need to fix your data first.

Comment: @Jeffrey Wieder please read note.

Answer (score 1):

*I didn't think this is possible to do automatically (but I was wrong :)).
When you run `EXEC sp_msforeachtable` this really runs for each table seperately, meaning the constraints where the check constraint would conflict with existing data are not applied (and you see the errors from those tables)*

So my idea is to execute the enabling of all constraints in all tables for once and then look on what tables there are still constraints that could not get activated. (and on those tables we will deactivate the other constraints as well...)

From [here](http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/464895-how-check-if-db-constraints-enabled-database) I got this nice thingy:

```
SELECT name, tbl = object_name(parent_obj)
FROM sysobjects
WHERE objectproperty(id, 'CnstIsDisabled') = 1
```

Now that gets you all constraints and their table name that are disabled.
After you executed `EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all"` the tables that have some constraint errors on them should show up in this query (but possibly multiple times due to possibly multiple constraints that failed on the same table).

You can modify that a little further into

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbl = object_name(parent_obj), 'EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ' + object_name(parent_obj) + ' NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"'
FROM sysobjects
WHERE objectproperty(id, 'CnstIsDisabled') = 1
```

Now you got executable statements in the last column you should be able to just select all rows of the last column and execute, then you should have constraints active only on those tables where all constraints could get activated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ideal solution by any means...but if you want a quick and dirty way to systematically go through all your tables and try to enable constraints here is how i would do it:

Write a program to do this for you.

Run this query to get a list of all table names:

```
selectTABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' 

foreach TABLE_NAME 
{
    try{
        ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
    }
    catch{}
}
```

The better solution would be to fix the data in the tables that you cannot enable this on and just enable it on all. I would suggest doing that over the partial enabling.